# How to collect logs via fluentd in swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, fluentd

I try to run services (mongo) in swarm mode with log collected to elasticsearch via fluentd. It's worked(!) with:

```
docker-compose up
```

But when I deploy via stack, services started, but logs not collected, and i don't know how to see what the reason.

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml env_staging
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:3.6.3
        depends_on:
         - fluentd
        command: mongod
        networks:
         - webnet
        logging:
          driver: "fluentd"
          options:
            fluentd-address: localhost:24224
            tag: mongo
    fluentd:
        image: zella/fluentd-es
        depends_on:
         - elasticsearch
        ports:
         - 24224:24224
         - 24224:24224/udp
        networks:
         - webnet
    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch
        ports:
         - 9200:9200
        networks:
         - webnet
    kibana:
        image: kibana
        depends_on:
         - elasticsearch
        ports:
         - 5601:5601
        networks:
         - webnet
networks:
     webnet:
```

**upd**

I remove `fluentd-address: localhost:24224` and problem solves. But I don't understand what is "localhost"? Why we can't set "fluentd" host. If someone explain what is `fluentd-address`, I will accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

`fluentd-address` is the address where fluentd daemon resides (default is localhost and you don't need to specify it in this case).

In your case (using stack) your fluentd daemon will run on a node, you should reach that service using the name of the service (in your case `fluentd`, have you tried?).

Remember to add to your options the `fluentd-async-connect: "true"`

Reference is at: 
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/#usage

Comment: I tried several times with `fluentd-address: localhost:24224` and `fluentd-address: fluentd:24224`. with "localhost" service fail to start.  When I use "fluentd" host there are no logs in es. Only without this lines it's working. So i not sure, that "localhost" is default value

Comment: inside your webnet, can you ping fluentd? Do you receive a response?

Comment: I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346005/cant-log-from-fluentd-logdriver-using-service-name-in-compose And default host 127.0.0.1 which works

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify fluentd-address. When you set logging driver to fluentd, Swarm automatically discovers nearest fluentd instance and sends there all stdout of desired container.