# How to use fluent-bit with Docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, fluent-bit

I want to use the fluent-bit docker image to help me persist the ephemeral docker container logs to a location on my host (and later use it to ship logs elsewhere).

I am facing issues such as:

```
Cannot start service clamav: failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:24224: connect: connection refused
```

I have read a number of post including
[configuring fluentbit with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232151/configuring-fluentbit-with-docker) but I'm still at a lost.

My docker-compose is made up of nginx, our app, keycloak, elasticsearch and clamav. I have added fluent-bit, made it first to starts via depends on. I changed the other services to use the fluentd logging driver.

Part of config:

```
clamav:
  container_name: clamav-app
  image: tiredofit/clamav:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./clamav/data:/data
    - ./clamav/logs:/logs
  environment:
    - ZABBIX_HOSTNAME=clamav-app
    - DEFINITIONS_UPDATE_FREQUENCY=60
  networks:
    - iris-network
  expose:
    - "3310"
  depends_on:
    - fluentbit
  logging:
    driver: fluentd

fluentbit:
  container_name: iris-fluent
  image: fluent/fluent-bit:latest
  restart: always
  networks:
    - iris-network
  volumes:
    - ./fluent-bit/etc:/fluent-bit/etc
  ports:
    - "24224:24224"
    - "24224:24224/udp"
```

I have tried to proxy_pass 24224 to fluentbit in nginx and start nginx first, and that avoided the error on clamav and es, but same error with keycloak.

So how can I configure the service to use the host or is it that localhost is not the "external" host?